# Toggling an admin user with a form RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking at creating a toggle button for current admins to toggle user admin status on/off. From my understanding I will require some json to perform this but I am very limited in this category and am just a beginner to programming in general. I am using rails v5.0.1 and ruby v2.3.2 Information about how I want this to work:

1. An admin will access the Users Index where he/she will be able to search through all users
2. Each user can be deleted or admin on/off toggled via Administrative actions developed with before_actions (in controllers) and if/else methods (in views)

NOTE: My User table is name:string, email:string, and admin:boolean default:false (for obvious reasons). though it doesn't matter the passwords are pass/passconfirm with a digest.

I have searched everywhere but I either get a routing issue when trying to send a patch request or a simple syntax error because I tried something new

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    include UsersHelper
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index]
    before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :admin_user, only: [ :destroy]

    def index
        @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            log_in @user
            flash[:success]= "Welcome #{@user.name}!"
            redirect_to user_path(@user)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            flash[:success]= "#{@user.name} you have successfully updated account information"
            redirect_to user_path(@user)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        User.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "User deleted"
        redirect_to users_url
    end

        private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end

        def logged_in_user
            unless logged_in?
                flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
                redirect_to login_url
            end
        end

        # Confirms the correct user.
        def correct_user
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
            redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
        end

        def admin_user
            redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
        end

        def make_admin
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
            @user.toggle!(:admin)
            redirect_to users_path
        end
end
```

and my users/index.html.erb:

```
  <h1>Users Index</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
      <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %> |
      <%= button_to [:make_admin, @user] do %>
      Make <%= @user.name%> an admin?

      <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> |

    </li>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate %>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the error? Also I think the `button_to do` block you have extends to far (i.e. I'm pretty sure you want this `<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %> |
      <%= button_to [:make_admin, @user] do %>
      Make <%= @user.name%> an admin?
      <% end %>

      <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> |

    <% end %>    </li>` instead of what you have

Comment: @SomeSchmo Ah I see what you mean, I actually did find that I misplaced <% end %> but still didn't fix my routing issue. I used the routing as below, and was able to get past the routing error but now face  the issue of an undefined method of "id" following the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first don't let the method on private because with that, the method isn't accesible directly, that's the first part. just put the method above the `private` line.

and if you have for example in your routes a resources for user, add this

```
resources :users do
  match :make_admin, :via => [:get]
end
```

then let's go with the link

```
<%= link_to user_make_admin_path(user.id) do %>
  Make <%= user.name%> an admin?
<% end%>
```

Comment: (your routing works thank you!) but I've done as you said but get an error for undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass for line 11 (ie <%= link_to user_make_admin_path(@user.id) do %>

Comment: I used @user.id as an example, you have to change "@user.id" for the variable or param that contains the id of the user, in your example it seems to be user.id, without the "@"

Comment: "@user.id" should fetch said user of <% @users.each do |user| though right?

Comment: if you are using the view that you added, just do that, remove the @ on both parts of the link, I will edit it to let everything correct

Comment: <ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
      <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %> |
      <%= link_to user_make_admin_path(user.id) do %>
     <% end %>
      <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>   
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end % Though I did just realize I have no button for link XD

Comment: just add a text between <%= link_to user_make_admin_path(user.id) do %> *some text for the link* <% end %>

Comment: Okay so now I get an error "Couldn't find User with 'id'=" unsure whats wrong,

Comment: are you sure that params[:id] is filled? try changing it with params[:user_id] in make_admin action. if this doesn't work, see the params that are on the request.

Comment: Ah that does work, can you explain to me why (params[:id]) is different that that of (params[:user_id). When I searched my server logs says:   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "admin" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["admin", true], ["updated_at", 2017-04-24 21:31:59 UTC], ["id", 3]]
   (14.4ms)  commit transaction

Comment: params[:id] and params[:user_id] are two different params, it contains what you tell them to contain, the thing here is the way we defined the routes. the resources :xyzs add a params[:id] to every request so we know that the restful will have that param, but the match, add the params[:xyzs_id] by default instead of params[:id]

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, if I remember that the next time I try this I might make some progress haha. Thank you very much for all your time!

Comment: haha you will, don't worry, or you can comeback and see it! mark this as accepted if you want, have a good day. we are here to help!

Comment: Oh I was also going to ask, If i make a :get request via match am I more prone to csfr or is rails by default pretty good at handling such requests?

Comment: there is no difference in the way the route is defined, even in resources you have get requests, like edit, show and index. You have protect_from_forgery with: :exception on the application controller that prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception. but you can try to add more on this by yourself

Comment: I should have worded that question different As I was wondering if there was a difference in the the route is defined